# Route traffic from a daemon through a specific interface

Tags: iptables, route

I have a server with two interfaces: `eth0` and `dummy0`, both have different public IP.

How to route all traffic from specific program (daemon) through dummy0, using iptables?

I want the daemon to establish an internet connection via a different public IP, that i have on the `dummy0` interface.

I need the demon traffic to be routed only through the second public IP address of my server.

I've tried many examples, but with no success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the daemon to establish an internet connection via a different public IP, that i have on the dummy0 interface.

That's not how it works with dummy interfaces.

Best solution: Make a networking namespace, run your demon (and every other program that should use the second IP) in the networking namespace, have `macvlan` in the networking namespace with your second IP with `eth0` as master.

Another possible solution: Add second IP to `eth0`, make sure every single program you run supports binding to IP addresses, and picks either the first IP or the second IP. Otherwise they may end up picking a random IP. That's a considerable headache, so I recommend the first solution.

> I've tried many examples, but with no success...

I am not surprised.

Comment: Googling "macvlan network namespace tutorial" gives quite a few hits. Try those out, if you get stuck, ask a new question. I've also posted a script to create a network namespace (with veth-pair, but you can modify this) either here or on superuser, use the search function.